# C# cast - input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When trying to run the following program code, this error occurred;

"Input string was not in a correct format."

The project breaks at the point below.

```
int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - double.Parse(lblBytesSent.Text)) / 1024;
```

Code;

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InterfaceTrafficWatch
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Network Interface Traffic Watch
    /// by Mohamed Mansour
    /// 
    /// Free to use under GPL open source license!
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Timer Update (every 1 sec)
        /// </summary>
        private const double timerUpdate = 1000;

        /// <summary>
        /// Interface Storage
        /// </summary>
        private NetworkInterface[] nicArr;

        /// <summary>
        /// Main Timer Object 
        /// (we could use something more efficient such 
        /// as interop calls to HighPerformanceTimers)
        /// </summary>
        private Timer timer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeNetworkInterface();
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize all network interfaces on this computer
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeNetworkInterface()
        {
            // Grab all local interfaces to this computer
            nicArr = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            // Add each interface name to the combo box
            for (int i = 0; i < nicArr.Length; i++)
                cmbInterface.Items.Add(nicArr[i].Name);

            // Change the initial selection to the first interface
            cmbInterface.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the Timer
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = (int)timerUpdate;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update GUI components for the network interfaces
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateNetworkInterface()
        {
            // Grab NetworkInterface object that describes the current interface
            NetworkInterface nic = nicArr[cmbInterface.SelectedIndex];

            // Grab the stats for that interface
            IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();

            // Calculate the speed of bytes going in and out
            // NOTE: we could use something faster and more reliable than Windows Forms Tiemr
            //       such as HighPerformanceTimer http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2006/12/21/high_resolution_timer_in_net_2_0.html
            int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - double.Parse(lblBytesSent.Text)) / 1024;
            int bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - double.Parse(lblBytesReceived.Text)) / 1024;

            // Update the labels
            lblSpeed.Text = nic.Speed.ToString();
            lblInterfaceType.Text = nic.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString();
            lblSpeed.Text = nic.Speed.ToString();
            lblBytesReceived.Text = interfaceStats.BytesReceived.ToString();
            lblBytesSent.Text = interfaceStats.BytesSent.ToString();
            lblUpload.Text = bytesSentSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s";
            lblDownload.Text = bytesReceivedSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s";

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Timer event for each Tick (second) to update the UI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateNetworkInterface();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception means the string you are trying to parse does not have a valid double value.

Just do

```
double bytesSent = 0.0;
if(double.TryParse(lblBytesSent.Text, out bytesSent))
{
    int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - bytesSent) / 1024;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug and check what the value of lblBytesSent is on that line - it's probably not a number for one reason or another.